# Customer Reviews is not showing up on Product Detail page in magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.7 version 
On product detail page Review form is showing but customer reviews and their rating is not showing.
I checked in front-end this div is empty

```
<div id="product-review-container" data-role="product-review"></div>
```

i also checked this [Reviews not showing up on Product View (after upgrade from Magento 2.1.3 to 2.2.3)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224068/reviews-not-showing-up-on-product-view-after-upgrade-from-magento-2-1-3-to-2-2)
but no one answered here.

I also follow this 
[Magento 2.2 move review tab below description with all product reviews](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209256/magento-2-2-move-review-tab-below-description-with-all-product-reviews)
But not getting proper answer.

Comment: The reviews are approved by admin?

Comment: yes, it is approved from admin.

Comment: is any one there who face same problem ?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: i can see all reviews in admin but wouldn't be displayed in frontend any solution