# Product reviews not showing in tab in magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, review, product-review

This thread is similar to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238930/customer-reviews-is-not-showing-up-on-product-detail-page-in-magento-2-1-7)
I have a problem with displaying product reviews in tab , i can insert a review but the reviews are not showing (in tab title i see the number of the reviews) , the #product-review-container div is empty